# Extracting a part of a long text

Tags: java, string, split

Consider we have this `String`

```
    String Description="{"DN":"Systems and Software Verification: Model-Checking Techniques and Tools","D":"Model checking is a powerful approach for the formal verification of software. It automatically provides complete proofs of correctness, or explains, via counter-examples, why a system is not correct. Here, the author provides a well written and basic introduction to the new technique. The first part describes in simple terms the theoretical basis of model checking: transition systems as a formal model of systems, temporal logic as a formal language for behavioral properties, and model-checking algorithms. The second part explains how to write rich and structured temporal logic specifications in practice, while the third part surveys some of the major model checkers available.","S":[{"Ty":1,"U":"http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1965314"},{"Ty":1,"U":"http://ci.nii.ac.jp/ncid/BA52610493"}]}";
```

What I want to do is to extract is this string:

```
"Model checking is a powerful approach for the formal verification of software. It automatically provides complete proofs of correctness, or explains, via counter-examples, why a system is not correct. Here, the author provides a well written and basic introduction to the new technique. The first part describes in simple terms the theoretical basis of model checking: transition systems as a formal model of systems, temporal logic as a formal language for behavioral properties, and model-checking algorithms. The second part explains how to write rich and structured temporal logic specifications in practice, while the third part surveys some of the major model checkers available."
```

Using :

```
String text=Description.split("D"+":").toString();
```

does not work and even if does, the useless characters come after the desired text is unnecessary. What to do?

Comment: This file is JSON format - use Jackson or GSON libraries - see http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The string you gave won't even compile because there is an unquoted bracket at the beginning.  But in any case, you should be using a JSON parser to handle this, _not_ a regex.  Look into using GSON, and there are a ton of references here on SO and on the web.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but this Json object is within another object, means I need to first, use something like `String text = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("E");` to get what i have posted. Now what?